# Android TextView, move a specified character in the textview to a specified position?

Tags: android, textview

Let's say, I have a TextView with Text "Hello world!". By whatever means, It is shown as

```
Hel
lo 
wor
ld!
```

Now I want to move the content of the TextView so that the 'w' character is at somewhere like (0, 10) in the TextView. Is it possible to achieve this without overriding the text processing logic of TextView?

---

I want to retain the position of the text when the size of the TextView changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to override the text processing and the measuring and drawing. Seems pretty daunting. Maybe if you tell us what you're trying to achieve we can suggest another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind whitespace you could insert a number of spaces before inserting your character to push the character to the right position.

Comment: I think moving the content implies not modifying it.